# C# / Selenium - failing to find XPath text using contains()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have and html element that I wish to click using Selenium:

```html
<a class="epi-navigation-global_user_settings_shell_search " href="DatabaseJob.aspx?pluginId=20">
                                            Importer obligationsliste
                                        </a>
```

With the following xpath: `/html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[19]/a`

I attempt to click the element containing the text `"Importer obligationsliste"` by the following expression:

```cs
var obligationButton = By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Importer')]");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(obligationButton)).Click();
```

Yet the element is never found. I've also tried the full string `Importer obligationsliste` to no avail.
Any ideas why the element is not being found? I suspect it has to do with the whitespace around the text, but `contains()` should also be able to find substrings.

Comment: Is the elemtn inside aniframe

Comment: @PDHide No, just a regular element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp and read about writing xpath. Grabbing paths from Chrome is the worst thing you can do. Those paths take longer to find and are extremely brittle. On dev change adding a div, ul or li and your path will break.

If it is not in an iframe, try these:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Importer obligationsliste')]
//a[normalize-space()='Importer obligationsliste']
```

Comment: I'm not using that XPath, I only posted it to show where the actual element I'm looking for is positioned.

Comment: You are right, it is indeed an iframe, just so far up I didn't realize. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The text **Importer obligationsliste** have a lot of leading and trailing whitespaces. So to `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPath* with `contains()` for the text *Importer obligationsliste*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[contains(., 'Importer obligationsliste')]"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *XPath* with `normalize-space()` for the text *Importer obligationsliste*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space()='Importer obligationsliste']"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@class='epi-navigation-global_user_settings_shell_search ' and starts-with(@href, 'DatabaseJob')]"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *PartialLinkText*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.PartialLinkText("Importer obligationsliste"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("a.epi-navigation-global_user_settings_shell_search[href^='DatabaseJob']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, thanks for helping out. Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions succeed in obtaining the element. It's as if the element simply doesn't exist.